# What are the various rules for placement of goal kicks?

Tags: rules, football

I have seen goal kicks placed in various spots within the box, and then there are kicks where the goalkeeper can handle the ball and drop-kick it.

What determines these different cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are all completely different situations.

- A **goal kick** can only be taken within the goal area (the 6 yard box). ([Law 16](https://www.theifab.com/laws/chapter/36/section/106/))
- A **drop kick** means the ball is still in play. The goalie could as well throw the ball to a team mate.
- **Free kicks** can be awarded almost anywhere on the pitch. They're taken from where the previous offence occurred. ([Law 13](https://theifab.com/laws/chapter/33/section/98/))

Comment: Law 13.2, a free kick **can** be *awarded* anywhere on the field, just not *taken* (if for an attacker) inside the goal area.